# jQuery - Why document unloading stops my requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Some pages on my application are very, very slow to display, for normal reasons (business intelligence, that calls many external APIs, etc.). Sometimes, 3-5 minutes are needed.

I want to display a progress bar with text, notifying the user what's currently going on and why he's waiting.

Here's how I imagined the feature:
Every time the user displays a page, a new token is generated in the form. When he submits the form, while the browser waits for the response, a route can be called with the given token, that returns an JSON response giving the percentage of progress and the operation currently being done.

So, I wrote a little jQuery code that polls this route, and updates the progress bar as well.

```
var pollAjax = function () {
this.url         = '';
this.interval    = 5000;
this.callback    = '';
this.running     = true;
this.poll        = function poll() {
    var that = this;
    if (that.running) {
        $.get(that.url, function (data) {
            that.callback(data);
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.poll();
            }, that.interval);
        });
    }
};
this.setInterval = function setInterval(interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    return this;
};
this.setCallback = function setCallback(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    return this;
};
this.setUrl      = function setUrl(url) {
    this.url = url;
    return this;
};
this.stop        = function stop() {
    this.running = false;
    return this;
}
};

$(document).ready(function () {

var progressBars = $('.progress .progress-bar');

progressBars.each(function () {
    var progressPoll = new pollAjax();
    var progressBar  = $(this);
    progressPoll.setUrl($(this).data('refreshurl'));
    progressPoll.setInterval(2000);
    progressPoll.setCallback(function (data) {
        if (data.progress) {
            $('#progressbar').show();
            progressPoll.setInterval(200);
            progressBar.attr('data-transitiongoal', data.progress.percentage).progressbar();
            $('#progress_text').text(data.progress.text);
            console.log(data.progress);
        }
    });
    progressPoll.poll();
});

});
```

Sorry for the code quality, I'm better with PHP :)

This code works fine. When I fake some data in the poll url, the progressbar correctly updates every 200ms.

My problem is that this code stops working as soon as the user leaves the page (and that's bad because this is when I want the code to be triggered). 
When he submits the form, the page is still displayed while the browser is waiting long minutes for the response, but the automatic poll **immediately stops**. As if the unload event prevents scripts to continue running, even if the page is still displayed.

Do you know how I can handle this ?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can't your form submission be via AJAX either?

Comment: This would make me do significant modifications on the actual code.
Besides, this is not only the form, I'd like to have the progress bar behaviour on several links as well. 

I won't turn them into forms just for this functionnality, I'd prefer to give up if it's not possible.

Before changing everything I'd like at least to understand why everything stops as soon as a link is clicked or a form is submitted, and if the behaviour can be bypassed.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: When the document unloads, all the Javascript code stops working, because the browser is processing the new stuff that's loading. As soon as it's a synchronous process, the browser can't handle both at the same time.

Comment: Hey, I just figured out a problem I've never faced before: session locking in PHP. If my ajax requests point at a simple json file, they're not stopped while the browser is loading. If I have a _session_start()_ in my PHP code, Ajax requests keep _pending_ forever as long as the session lock is not released.

Comment: So... this is becoming a PHP issue more than a JS one. 
I tried a _session_write_close();_ (and the Symfony _$session->save()_ too), but this doesn't do the trick. It looks like the simple fact of  having a _session_start()_ somewhere, blocks everything, even if session is closed with a _session_write_close();_ afterwards. Any ideas?

Comment: I have never worked with PHP, sorry.